# tinyMCE - point between block elements

Tags: tinymce

I am using tinyMCE in show block elements mode.

I have written custom plugin that inserts prepared html blocks (layout partials) in actual cursor position.

It's problematic to point a space between two divs.

If I have markup like that:

```
<div id="first"></div><div id="second"></div>
```

When I click beteween those divs I would land in first or second div, never between.

So I try to edit html source and result in markup whit br's:

```
<div id="first"></div><br/><div id="second"></div>
```

Now I can point between those divs, but **it does not work with elements that I add dynamically via tinyMCE**. If I add partial eg.

```
<div></div><br/>
```

clicking after that div is not posibble. But it's posibble when I edit source manually. Weird. Do you have any solution at this subject?

Answer (score 0):

Tinymce takes care that the user is not able to click between div or p tags.
The reason for this is easy: If a user could click inbetween and he would type in a letter - then there would be another div or p created containing that letter. This is not the way rtes are designed to work. If you want to insert somthing between two divs you will need to use a special button or own plugin to take care of this, but placing the cursor where you won't it to be by hand won't work.